# Image auto fit container by height and weight

Tags: jquery, css

I found good jquery plugin that auto scale image to the browser screen on the container by weight. But I need to scale also by height. Any ideas how to do that with jquery or css? thanks.

example (scale only by weight)

> jsfiddle.net/nottrobin/9Pbdz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting a width of 100% on the image element itself, the browser will take care of the height scale automatically. No need for any JS or explicit heights set.

```
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

You can achieve the same auto-scaling 'height-wise' by setting an explicit height on the parent element, and then setting height: 100%; on the nested image element. Do not set a width on the image to preserve its ratio.

```
div {
    height: 100px;
}
img {
    height: 100%
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9Pbdz/84/

---

A dynamic image height can be achieved by following the same principle. Here's an example that gives the parent element a dynamic height based on window height. The image then fills the height of its parent and scales appropriately.

http://jsfiddle.net/9Pbdz/85/

---

This should get you close to a completed example:

http://jsfiddle.net/9Pbdz/92/

Comment: thanks, the second example with Jquery is almost what I want, but it's scale only by window height. Can image be scaled by window wight&height at the same time?

Comment: or maybe it's good idea to modify original `imagefit` code and add height functionality? `http://jquery-imagefit-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.imagefit-0.2.js`

Comment: One or the other should take care of most situations, and unless you have something quite unique going on, either scaling by height (as in the example above), or simply by width (http://jsfiddle.net/9Pbdz/83/) should suffice.

Comment: If you absolutely need both, then you may need to figure out how to branch the approaches so that the width styling is affected on window width resize, and height on window height resize... but that's really getting out there. The challenge is that this can't be done with 100% values to both width and height in your CSS, because that destroys the image ratio.

Comment: I am trying to find javascript to made this behaviour `http://www.socwall.com/desktop-wallpaper/55071//` Do you know how to make this? Maybe I need to create new question and acept this answer?

Comment: You could build something similar by using the jQuery provided in the jsfiddle above as a starting point, and setting a variable for the height as well as the width. You would then set up your parent div to maintain the same aspect ratio as your image, and alter the height and width based on how the window resize would affect that ratio. In that case, you could use height: 100%; and width: 100%; on your image in the CSS, because the parent div would enforce the image aspect ratio. Your javascript would need to include some math to calculate and enforce that ratio against the resizing effects.

Comment: I've added an example path to the solution in the answer, and at: http://jsfiddle.net/9Pbdz/92/

Answer (score 0):

set the dimensions of the containing div specifically to the height and weight and then set the css class of the image to be height:100% and width:100%